# Generic Repository Pattern for large and small objects

Tags: c#, rest, oop

We are working on an application (C# API with SQL Server and VueJS) where we are creating a generic repository. But we notice that performance drops when the objects are getting larger over time (number of properties grows to 30-40).

This means that for the `GetAll`, too much data is transferred to the client, but for the `GetById`, it is needed. We now set properties to nullable and don't serialise those to the client but this feels wrong.

We currently use something like this, for example (not actual code or subject):

```cs
public interface IGenericRepository<T, I>
{
    T GetById(I id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll(BaseFilter filter); // Used to search
    void Create(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(I id);
}

public class Country 
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string SubRegion { get; set; }
    public List<Municipality> Municipalities { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When we use the `GetAll` only the properties `ID` and `Name` are actually needed but when using the `GetById` we need all the properties. We are thinking about something like this.

```cs
public interface IGenericRepository<TypeSmall, TypeLarge, I>
{
    TypeLarge GetById(I id);
    IEnumerable<TypeSmall> GetAll(BaseFilter filter); // Used to search
    void Create(TypeLarge entity);
    void Update(TypeLarge entity);
    void Delete(I id);
}

public class CountryBase // TypeSmall
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}

public class Country : CountryBase // TypeLarge
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string SubRegion { get; set; }
    public List<Municipality> Municipalities { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

We are looking for the best way to achieve, what are your thoughts and experiences?

Comment: May I ask what actual value the generic-repository adding to your project?

Comment: @Dai the value for us is that it enforce us to write code in the same style, maintain a generic way of programming and speed of implementation. We also have generic services and controllers so setting up a new endpoint is easy and fast.

Comment: What do you do if an entity has a composite-key, for example? Or if an entity cannot exist by itself, but instead must exist as part of a larger object-graph? How does your `void Update()` method allow you to handle concurrency issues?

Comment: IMHO enforce the rule; `IGenericRepository<TypeSmall, TypeLarge, I> where TypeLarge : TypeSmall`. And put the old interface back for when you don't need it `IGenericRepository<T, I> : IGenericRepository<T,T,I>`.

Comment: You might want to add an explicit interface to describe the key values? `IHasKey<I> { I ID { get; set; }` ... `IGenericRepository<TS,TL,I> where TS : IHasKey<I>`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman that is what will do `public interface IHasIdentifier<I> { I ID { get;  } string DisplayName { get; } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* must do this, you can skip by the following admonitions to read a proposed solution, but first, some words of warning.

Ever [since C# got generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-20), people have been trying to implement such generic CRUD repositories. After almost two decades of that, the consensus is that this looks like an anti-pattern. (I can't list a single authoritative source backing up that claim, but try your favourite search engine - it isn't too hard to find content on that topic.)

If you do have a CRUD-heavy application backed by a relational database, there is, indeed, a tendency to have quite a lot of boilerplate code. If so, consider using an existing [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping). The most common choice in .NET is [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/). (I'm [not particular fond of ORMs myself](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/09/18/do-orms-reduce-the-need-for-mapping), but that's context-dependent so may not apply here.)

With that out of the way, if you insist going down the generic-repository route, there's no reason to make the 'small' model generic, since it's identical for all models. Just define a single interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string ID { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Then define the repository interface like this:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T, I>
{
    T GetById(I id);
    IEnumerable<IEntity> GetAll(BaseFilter filter); // Used to search
    void Create(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(I id);
}
```

Notice that `GetAll` no longer returns anything that depends on `T` or `I`.

You may, however, consider parametrizing `IEntity` on `I`, like this:

```
public interface IEntity<I>
{
    I ID { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

In any case, the entity classes can implement `IEntity`.